# lein-doo not running the tests, what's going on?

Tags: clojurescript

When I try running the tests with lein-doo I get this error:

```
ERROR: doo was not loaded from the compiled script.

Make sure you start your tests using doo-tests or doo-all-tests
and that you include that file in your build
```

My `project.clj` looks like this:

```
(defproject tech.dashman/clientcommon "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "Dashman - Common library to all clients"
  :url "https://dashman.tech"

  :min-lein-version "2.3.4"

  :source-paths ["src"]

  :cljsbuild {:builds {:test {:source-paths ["src" "test"]
                              :compiler     {:output-to  "target/test/clientcommon.js"
                                             :output-dir "target/test"
                                             :target     :nodejs
                                             :main       clientcommon.test-runner}}}}

  :doo {:build "test"
        :debug true}                                        ; Run tests: lein doo phantom

  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0" :scope "provided"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.9.229" :scope "provided"]
                 [com.taoensso/sente "1.11.0"]
                 [mount "0.1.10"]
                 [prismatic/schema "1.1.3"]
                 [cljsjs/react-with-addons "15.2.1-0"]
                 [reagent "0.6.0" :exclusions [cljsjs/react]]
                 [re-frame "0.8.0"]
                 [tech.dashman/reagent-toolbox "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"]
                 [doo "0.1.7"]]

  :plugins [[s3-wagon-private "1.3.0"]
            [lein-cljsbuild "1.1.4"]
            [lein-doo "0.1.7"]])
```

and my test-runner file looks like this:

```
(ns clientcommon.test-runner
  (:require [doo.runner :refer-macros [doo-tests doo-all-tests]]
            [clientcommon.crypto-test]
            [clientcommon.util-test]))

(doo-tests 'clientcommon.crypto-test
           'clientcommon.util-test)
```

I'm doing this on Windows and I found a related bug but it claims to be fixed: https://github.com/bensu/doo/issues/60

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: The dependency is: `[lein-doo "0.1.7"]` not `[doo "0.1.7"]`

Comment: @MrOerni, [lein-doo ...] is a plugin, not dependency. This includes both doo and lein-doo in what look like the right places.

Comment: @Mnebuerquo You are right. Today I know better. :-)

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause of your problem, but my `:source-paths` value in project.clj is this: `:source-paths ["src/cljs" "test/cljs"]`. Here's my project.clj from a reagent project where I have added my own test file with a few tests: https://github.com/JimTheMan/Jims-ClojureScript-Bakery/blob/master/bakery-app/project.clj Also, I didn't need to explicitly put ":doo" anywhere in my project.clj file.